# Convert Kotlin Android app using Project Astoria

Tags: android, win-universal-app, kotlin, windows-10

I'm going to develop an Android app using the Kotlin language instead of Java. Will I be able to later convert this app to be executed on Windows 10 devices using Project Astoria?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, Project Astoria works on binary files, so it won't care what compiler produced them: Java or Kotlin. Thus, yes, it will very probably work.

Comment: Yeah that's my doubt too, I wanted to know if the conversion is performed from the compilation result, or from source code.